# SQL server filter index with LIKE and RIGHT function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

This is self-study problem not in live environment.

I'm querying names end with A constantly so I thought I would create an filter index on such data, so it would do seek instead or scan.

But it's giving me error.

```
--Usual Query 
SELECT c.contactname
FROM sales.Customers c where c.contactname like '%A'

--1st Tried failed
create NONCLUSTERED INDEX UCI_NameLikeA
on sales.customers(contactname)
where right(contactname,1)='A'

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'

--2nd method tried failed
create NONCLUSTERED INDEX UCI_NameLikeA
on sales.customers(contactname)
where right(contactname,1)='A'

Msg 10735, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect WHERE clause for filtered index 'UCI_NameLikeA' on table 'sales.customers'.
```

Why Like and RIGHT function isn't allowed in filter index? any other method with I can do seek instead of scan?

Comment: You could create an indexed view with `where c.contactname like '%A'` as filtered indexes are quite limited. Then select from that `with(noexpand)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188783.aspx there are only simple operators allowed to filter the index.

So you can choose non computed columns and like `=` `<` `>` and `IN()`

**Edit:**

What you can do.
Create another column where you 1st letter is stored.
Then create a index that update this column like this:

```
UPDATE [mytable]
SET [index_column] = RIGHT(contactname,1)
```

There you can set your INDEX, may be this help your approach.

Comment: @VishwanathDalvi :He can create another column which stores `contactName` in `reverse Order` and then create `Index` on it. So the query `Select  c.contactname
FROM sales.Customers c where c.contactname like 'A%'` will produce `Index Seek` or he can use `Full text Search`

Comment: If you're creating these columns (Rightmost letter or reversed string) for indexing, it's best to do it as a computed column so that there's no other maintenance required.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - You can't create a filtered index on a computed column though.

Comment: @MartinSmith - it was my understanding that the suggestions to have an alternative column containing the rightmost letter or the reversed string would allow an (un-filtered) index to be created which could assist this query.